# Any ideea why every NSIS setup file(.exe) i download gives CRC error?

Tags: windows-7, nsis

Any ideea why every NSIS setup file(.exe) i download gives CRC error when trying to install. 
I do not have any firewall installed and also i tried with and withouth a download manager. Also files downloaded with bittorrent have crc errors. But this happens only with setups that were made with NSIS and only on windows 7, on XP they work fine and aloso any other files work except those made with NSIS.

Comment: post the link of the NSIS setup file you are downloading

Comment: http://gamedaily.newaol.com/pub/ParabellumBeta_2009_10_27.exe

Comment: Try with extracting the installer using 7zip or WinRAR or similar. You may be able to access files inside the installer this way, but it still isn't a real solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a file virus which inserts itself into executables between downloading and execution. Try uploading one of the corrupted files to [Virustotal](http://www.virustotal.com/) for scanning.

Comment: I have updated antivirus installed. And if it was a virus i don't think he would've targeted only setups made by NSIS as i specified that everything else works.

Comment: I'm not sure what programs "everything else" includes but perhaps they don't check their own integrity the way NSIS installers do. Virustotal uses many different A/V programs, which is better than whatever *one* you are using.

Comment: everything else includes every setup file, selfextracting file, etc that was not made using nsis

Comment: @daniels It could be that your anti-virus actually corrupts NSIS files. There were cases where anti-virus programs detected NSIS installers as viruses. Otherwise, if you do submit the file to Virustotal, nothing bad will happen to you! Since all NSIS files are corrupt, you can use smaller one instead.